# Rigify: DEF-bone problem

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have a problem in rigging (rigify), it happened in face bone deform. In edit mode it looks normal, but when I switch to object/pose mode wierd thing happens. any suggestion?[image: DEF-cheek bone]

Comment: It's not quite clear which part of the rig you're showing, which stage that is (metarig/final rig?) etc. Try to add more info, explain what you did before you get this problem.

Comment: Agree. In addition, [sharing your .blend file with us](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) could really help us find out the issue.